# react-navigation v6 equivalent of push

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I need to push multiple instances of the same screen to the stack, and `.navigate()` does not achieve this. It just navigates to the instance already on the stack (same as a no-op). `.push` has been removed from `navigation` and `CommonActions` (formerly `StackActions`).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself:

```js
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

const state = navigation.getRootState().state;
const routes = state.routes;
routes.push({
  key: `ScreenName-${uniqueKey}`,
  name: "ScreenName",
  params: screenNameNavProps,
});
navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({ ...state, index: state.index + 1, routes });
```

Make sure you change `ScreenName` to your screen name, and assign a unique key to `uniqueKey` (I used a unique key from the navigation props for the screen).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a typing issue. The `push` method is still there ([see here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times)).

I was typing my navigation prop like this:

`navigation: NavigationProp<RootNavigatorType>;`

imported from `"@react-navigation/native";`

But the push method is in the stack navigator, so I had to replace the above for this:

`navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<MyCustomNavigatorType>;`

imported from `"@react-navigation/native-stack"`